# Hystrix Command - Async execution calling queue() method

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, hystrix

I have a class that is extending HystrixCommand class and I'm setting up the following thread pool properties:

- threadPoolSize: 10
- maximumSize: 10
- maxQueueSize: 20
- queueSizeRejectionThreshold: 50

Inside the run implementation I'm calling a REST client. I'm calling the queue() method for each command call and I'm storing the returned futures in a map for a later processing.

What I'm seeing in debug mode is that for each created command, the run method is being called in the main execution thread while I'm aiming to make the calls asynchronously.

According to the queue method documentation, "If configured to not run in a separate thread, this will have the same effect as execute() and will block.", What does it mean by "not configured to run in a separate thread"?

Comment: The [`HystrixCommand.queue()` Javadoc](https://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html#queue--) goes on to immediately say *We don't throw an exception but just flip to synchronous execution so code doesn't need to change in order to switch a command from running on a separate thread to the calling thread.* (which is the behavior you're seeing).  Instead of `HystrixCommand`, you might consider using `HystrixObservableCommand`.

Comment: Great @ElliottFrisch I'll give it a try. Thanks!